# Drawing from a vector of sprites SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Every object in my game world has a vector of sprites that visually represent that object. My issue is that i cant seem to draw them properly on the screen:

This is the drawable object that every drawable inherits from:

```
class Drawable {
private:
    static vector<Drawable*> sprites;
protected:
    vector<sf::Texture> myTextures;
    vector<sf::Sprite> mySprites;
public:
    Drawable();
    static vector<Drawable*> getSprites();
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow&) const;
};
```

And its .cpp:

```
vector<Drawable*> Drawable::drawables;
Drawable::Drawable() {
    drawables.push_back(this);
}

vector<Drawable*> Drawable::getDrawables() {
    return drawables;
}

void Drawable::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) const {
    for (auto sprite : mySprites) {
        window.draw(sprite);
    }
}
```

Example of a object that inherits from drawable:

```
class Terrain : public Drawable {
private:
    void loadSprite(string);
public:
    Terrain(string);
};
```

and its .cpp:

```
Terrain::Terrain(string fileName) {
    loadSprite(fileName);
}

void Terrain::loadSprite(string fileName) {
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile(fileName);
    myTextures.push_back(texture);

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    mySprites.push_back(sprite);
}
```

In this case the terrain sprite is only a white-box during run-time. I think this is because the "texture" and "sprite" var in loadSprite gets destroyed after the method goes out of scope.

I know i could probably solve the issue by saving "texture" and "sprite" in the terrain-class (not creating them locally in a method like now). But this seems unnecessary to me, cant i store them in the vectors mySprites and myTextures instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think this is because the "texture" and "sprite" var in loadSprite gets destroyed after the method goes out of scope.

You're right. [`sf::Sprite` stores a reference to `sf::Texture`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560). `loadSprite` would work one-time only if you'd do `sprite.setTexture(myTextures.back());`. But `std::vector`'s elements will be reallocated as you `push_back`. I recommend `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>` for simplicity.

Better yet, load all the textures at once, so that you don't have **duplicate** ones and use IDs to refer to them.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i tried the method i came up with. That is storing the sprite and texture in each object that uses them. So terrain.h would have two fields sf::Texture texture, sf::Sprite sprite and in loadSprite i assigned them and it worked :)

Comment: Also i changed so that vectors mySprites and myTextures now holds pointers (instead of making a copy) this would prevent duplicates